# Is it possible to save php values from a form for further use?

Tags: php, forms

I currently have a form on one page that calculates a value depending on what the user has entered:

```
// PROCESS USERS CALCULATIONS
    $ElecAQ = trim($_POST['ElecAQ']);
    $Elecday = trim($_POST['Elecday']);
    $Elecmonth = trim($_POST['Elecmonth']);
    $Elecyear = trim($_POST['Elecyear']);
    $Elecstanding_charge = trim($_POST['Elecstanding_charge']);

<input type="text" style="padding-left: 2px" class="text-box-find" name="ElecAQ" placeholder="0000" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ElecAQ'])) echo $_POST['ElecAQ'];?>">

  <input type="text" class="day" name="Elecday" style="float: left; margin-right: 2px" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Elecday'])) echo $_POST['Elecday'];?>" placeholder="DAY" />

<input type="text" class="month"  name="Elecmonth" placeholder="MONTH" style="float: left" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Elecmonth'])) echo $_POST['Elecmonth'];?>">    

<input type="text" class="year" name="Elecyear" placeholder="YEAR" style="float: left" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Elecyear'])) echo $_POST['Elecyear'];?>">  

<input type="text" style="padding-left: 2px" class="text-box-find" name="Elecstanding_charge" placeholder=".00" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Elecstanding_charge'])) echo $_POST['Elecstanding_charge'];?> ">
```

When this form gets submitted, the page refreshes and the user is shown a success message (the amount of money they could save) and another form prompting them to enter their details to request a quote underneath.

My question is: Is it going to be possible for me to save the values somehow that get entered into the first form and then send them in the email when then second form is submitted?

The page gets refreshed when the first form processed, so when the email is sent from the second form all the values from the first form that I have included the recieving email are blank.

I really hope that I have managed to explain this ok, I am hoping somebody can tell me the best way of doing this?

---

Here is the section of code to send the email once the second form is submitted:

```
$emailTo = 'email@email.co.uk';
    $subject = 'Savings Calculator -Submitted request from '.$name;
    $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
    $body = "First Name: $contactName \n\nBusiness Name: $businessname \n\nEmail: $email \n\nPhone: $phone \n\nMobile: $mobile \n\nBest time of day to call: $time\n\nUSERS CALCULATIONS: $_SESSION['ElecAQ']";

    $headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
```

Comment: You can store them temporary in `Session` and can access on second page or in email code. Please post your second page & email code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `session_start();` at top of your both pages.

Assigning values to session variable

```
$_SESSION['ElecAQ'] = trim($_POST['ElecAQ']);
```

Access session value

```
echo $_SESSION["ElecAQ"];
```

Try Example

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['ElecAQ'] = trim($_POST['ElecAQ']);
$_SESSION['$Elecday'] = trim($_POST['Elecday']);
$_SESSION['$Elecmonth'] = trim($_POST['Elecmonth']);
$_SESSION['$Elecyear'] = trim($_POST['Elecyear']);
$_SESSION['$Elecstanding_charge'] = trim($_POST['Elecstanding_charge']);

// access session values call
echo $_SESSION['ElecAQ'];
?>
```

**Email Code**

Just changed `USERS CALCULATIONS: $_SESSION['ElecAQ']";` into `USERS CALCULATIONS: ".$_SESSION['ElecAQ'];`

Updated

```
$emailTo = 'email@email.co.uk';
$subject = 'Savings Calculator -Submitted request from '.$name;
$sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
$body = "First Name: $contactName \n\nBusiness Name: $businessname \n\nEmail: $email \n\nPhone: $phone \n\nMobile: $mobile \n\nBest time of day to call: $time\n\nUSERS CALCULATIONS: ".$_SESSION['ElecAQ'];

$headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
```

Comment: ok great I have added the session details to the page but trying to access the value in the email body section gives me an error: arse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/

Comment: @user3018817 please provide the code of email section.

Comment: This is where I am trying to add the variable ($body = "First Name: $contactName \n\n ) - with the second form details - any idea? thanks for your help :)

Comment: @user3018817 access session like `$body = "First Name: ".$_SESSION['ElecAQ']." \n\n";`

Comment: I got the first one working thank you for your help! I can now finish my form

Answer (score 3):

you can use `$_SESSION` variable to save variables which can be then used to another form.

use `session_start();` at the top to start accessing session variables.

assign values to session variable.
`$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";`

to access `echo $_SESSION["favcolor"];`